# Always 403 Forbidden when fetching Google ClientLogin token from Appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-ads-api

I am trying to fetch a simple ClientLogin token.

My code looks like:

```
UrlFetchTransport urlFetchTransport = new UrlFetchTransport();

ClientLoginTokens clientLoginTokens = new ClientLoginTokens.Builder()
    .forApi(ClientLoginTokens.Api.ADWORDS)
    .withHttpTransport(urlFetchTransport)
    .withEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .build();

String clientLoginToken = clientLoginTokens.requestToken();
```

The code runs perfectly fine on my local machine and AppEngine's devserver (1.7.7). I end up with a nice clientLoginToken.

On production, however, I always get a 403 Forbidden (or 403 OK whatever that means) and I am never able to retrieve a clientLoginToken (ClientLoginResponseException: 403). My app is currently running on an http://APP.appspot.com domain (default AppEngine production url).

I already tried to use use the default transport and not UrlFetchTransport, but this does not change anything - it runs locally, but fails when running on AppEngine.

Any hints appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out this is a security "feature" of Google's ClientLogin.

AppEngine's servers are distributed worldwide - and Google makes sure nobody has stolen your account credentials. By default (and some unknown metric) Google blocks accesses to your account that do not come from your "computer" (or area I guess).

You can add additional applications by visiting:

https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

After entering your credentials you have 10 minutes to "add" access for another application. That solved it for me. But of course it'd be much better to use OAuth 2.0 what does not have those kind of issues.